# javascript trigger fullscreen

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullscreen

I tried to trigger fullscreen using javascript by clicking the button.

```
<button id="fullscreen" onClick="fullscreen()">fullscreen</button>
<script>
    function fullscreen(){
        var element = document.documentElement;
        if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            element.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
            element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
        }
    }
</script>
```

it works.

but I would like to trigger it automatically by adding

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fullscreen").click();
});
```

then it doesn't work.
can anyone help?

Comment: izzit suppose `$(function () {` or `$(document).ready(function(){`

Comment: 1. `$()` won't work. 2. `requestFullScreen` cannot be triggered automatically in some browsers.

Comment: thank you guys. $().ready(function(){.....}); it works, but I found it  isn't recommended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if you change `$()` to the correct syntax:

```
$(function() {
    $("#fullscreen").click();
});
```

This still won't work. Actually there is no way to make this work since `requestFullScreen` must<sup>[note 1]</sup> be initiated by an user action.

<sup>[note 1]</sup> Although not specified in [the specification](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/fullscreen/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#dom-element-requestfullscreen), most browsers will prevent `requestFullScreen` from being automatically triggered because of security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You can use setTimeout:

```
setTimeout(fullscreen,5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont

```
$(function(){
   fullscreen();
})
```